# Determine how many items are in Python JoinableQueue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I am using the Python `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` class and I'm trying to impose a size limit to the queue. If the queue is full up to this limit, the loop will sleep and try to re-add the task when space in the queue frees up, but I can't seem to find a reliable way to track the queue size.

I was thinking of using some logic like this, only to find out the `.qsize()` function I expected from the `Queue` module does not exist:

```
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue
QUEUE_SIZE = 50
QUEUE_WAIT = 900
task_queue = JoinableQueue(QUEUE_SIZE)
....
if QUEUE_SIZE is not 0:
    # if QUEUE_SIZE is zero, there is no limit on the queue
    while True:
        # if the size of the queue equals our self-imposed limit, wait to try and add this task
        if task_queue.qsize() == QUEUE_SIZE:
            print 'task queue limit is met. task will be added when space clears'
            time.sleep(QUEUE_WAIT)
        else:
            # add the task if we can
            self.task_queue.put(path)
            print 'task queued" task="%s"' % path)
            break

    else:
        # if there's no limit just add the file_path
        self.task_queue.put(file_path)
```

Is there a preferred way to track how many items are currently in a JoinableQueue, or perhaps a better way to re-try adding items to a queue if they cannot be added right away? Maybe just a `try / except / sleep` inside of a loop? This doesn't seem like the best option, though.

Any would is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: a `try / except / sleep` in a loop is probably the most appropriate way to do this (although I must admit, I've not used JoinableQueue before). However, tracking the size of something which is accessed from multiple threads outside of any locking that the JoinableQueue is performing seems a little icky.  You will still have to handle the `except` case anyway as there may be other reasons why the queue will not accept your item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JoinableQueue` should have a `.full()` method that you should be able to use to determine whether or not the queue has space for new items. Using `full()` instead of `qsize()` means that you can avoid having to track the maximum size of the queue separately.

However, I would avoid using this as it will be unreliable in the same way as `.qsize()`. The queue may be mid-modification when it's read, so you will have to handle the exception case anyway.  Using `try....except` inside a loop with a sleep is probably the clearest, safest and most practical way to achieve what you want to try.

Wrapping this in a helper function may make the code easier (you'd have to modify this to handle arguments to `func` or have wrap the call in a no-arg lambda before passing it to `try_until()`.

```
def try_until(func, max_tries, sleep_time):
    for _ in range(0,max_tries):
        try:
            return func()
        except:
            sleep(sleep_time)
    raise WellNamedException()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! 

I know that `.qsize()` is a bit unpredictable, unfortunately. I am also entering the queued items (which are file paths) into a MongoDB collection in order to avoid re-adding them when the directory is checked again, so perhaps I could keep track of the queued item count by checking the Mongo collection using this wrapper?